# print each word on a new line

Tags: c, getchar, putchar

I am trying to print each word on a new line. I have made it to scan for a space and then print new line. It cansput deletes some letters at times:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
char ch;
int nextChar;
    nextChar = getchar();
    while (ch != EOF) {
        if (ch == ' ') {
            putchar('\n');
        }
        else {
            putchar(ch);
        }
        ch = getchar();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For example Input: `hello how are you`

output:

```c
hello
how
are
you
```

Comment: You use wrong variable. You don't need the `ch`, `nextChar` is ok to use it.

Comment: Fyi, `ch` should be `int`, not `char`. And indeterminate evaluation is playing with UB fire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is you assign first char value to `nextChar` variable and use `ch` variable. To correct try the folowing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    char ch = getchar();
    while (ch != EOF) {
        if (ch == ' ') {
            putchar('\n');
        }
        else {
            putchar(ch);
        }
        ch = getchar();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

int nextChar;
    nextChar = getchar();

the above mentioned lines are apparently the reason you are facing that issue.
it'll store the first character in the nextChar variable however, you'll never end up using it. Hence the rest of the charaters in the input works as expected. And in the rest of sentences it works fine because the above mentioned useless lines are out of the scope of the while loop which actually does the job fine